# Prove that $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{2} \sin |t| (\phi''(t) + \phi(t)) dt = \phi(0)$ for any $\phi \in C^\infty_c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

How can I prove that $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{2} \sin |t| (\phi''(t) + \phi(t)) dt = \phi(0)$$ for any function $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: In the language of distribution theory, the intuition behind this is that $D^2+1$, where $D$ is derivative, can be moved from $\phi$ to $\sin |t|$. When $t \neq 0$ we have $(D^2+1) \sin|t| = 0$ and at $t=0$ we have $\sin|t| \sim |t|$ and $(D^2+1)|t| = D^2 |t| = 2 \delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution satisfying $\int \delta(t) \phi(t) \, dt = \phi(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Integrate by parts twice the term containing $\phi''$ and apply the fact the $\phi$ is of compact support.

Can you finish now?

Comment: But first, because of $|t|$, the integral needs to be split: $\int_{\mathbb R} = \int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^\infty$.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, it does.